# How to reproduce an animation right after one finishes in Phaser 3 Javascript

Tags: javascript, game-development, phaser-framework, phaserjs

So i have two animations, the first one is just two frames where the character just starts walking and the other is one where the character is walking, the second one is looped, im using anims.chain so the when the first one finishes it plays the next one, but it doesnt work, thanks in advance, here is the code (soma is the name of the character)

```
const velocity = 100;
export class Game extends Phaser.Scene{
    constructor(){
        super({key: 'game'})
    }
    init(){
        this.startWalkingPlayed = false;
    }

    preload(){
        this.load.image('soma', 'img/soma.png')
        this.load.image('placeholder', 'img/placeholder.png')
        this.load.spritesheet('walking-anim', 'img/walking-anim.png', {frameWidth: 32, frameHeight: 34})
    }

    create(){
        this.soma = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 10, 'soma')
        this.placeholder = this.physics.add.sprite(100, 150, 'placeholder').setImmovable();
        this.placeholder.scaleX = 20
        this.physics.add.collider(this.soma, this.placeholder)
        this.placeholder.body.allowGravity = false


        this.anims.create({
            key: 'startWalking',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('walking-anim', { start: 19, end: 20}),
            frameRate: 10
        })

        this.anims.create({
            key: 'walking',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('walking-anim', { start: 21, end: 37}),
            frameRate: 10
        })

        this.anims.create({
            key: 'idle',
            frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('walking-anim', { start: 1, end: 3}),
            frameRate: 2.3,
            yoyo: true
        })

        this.up = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.UP);
        this.left = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.LEFT);
        this.right = this.input.keyboard.addKey(Phaser.Input.Keyboard.KeyCodes.RIGHT);

        this.physics.world.setBounds(0, 0, 240, 160);
        this.soma.setCollideWorldBounds(true)
    }

    update(){
        this.soma.body.setVelocityX(0);

        if (this.left.isDown){
            this.soma.body.setVelocityX(-velocity);
            this.soma.flipX = true;
        }

        if (this.right.isDown){
            this.soma.body.setVelocityX(velocity);
            this.soma.flipX = false;
        }

        if ((this.left.isDown || this.right.isDown)){
            this.soma.anims.play('startWalking')
            this.soma.anims.chain('walking', true)
        }else{
            this.soma.anims.play('idle', true)
        }
    }
```

I already tried using listeners like sprite.on('animationcomplete-startWalking', listener) (I didnt exactly wrote it like that its just an example) but nothing, I also tried using a variable that checks if the frist animation already played so it can play the next animation, but still didnt work,

I just want the first animation to reproduce once, and then the next animation to play in loop immediately after

Comment: Just wanted to know, if my answer solved your issue, or is something missing? If it helped, please consider accepting my answer with the green checkmark under the voting arrows.

Answer (score 1):

There are several different ways to do this. Here I'm showcasing two different possibilities. One on moving left and a slightly different one on moving right.

**The main Idea on moving left:**

- If there is no X - Velocity play the start animation (in this case a **kick**)
- Else If there is a X - Velocity and no animation or not the **kick** animation is not playing, play the walk animation.

**The main Idea on moving right:**

- If there is no X - Velocity, start the animations in a `chain`, and since the **walk** animation runs in an infinite loop, you don't need to call the `play` function again.

> ***Info:** The expressions in the `if` can/should be altered to fit your needs.*

**Mini Demo:**
*(assets borrowed from [this official example](https://labs.phaser.io/edit.html?src=src%5Canimation%5Ccreate%20animation%20from%20sprite%20sheet.js))*

```js
document.body.style = 'margin:0;';

var config = {
    width: 536,
    height: 183,
    physics: { default: 'arcade' },
    scene: { preload, create, update },
};

function preload() {
    this.load.spritesheet('brawler', 'https://labs.phaser.io/assets/animations/brawler48x48.png', { frameWidth: 48, frameHeight: 48 });
}

function create() {
    this.add.text(10, 10, 'USE Arrow Keys to Move!', { fontSize:'18px' })
        .setOrigin(0)
        
    this.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();
    this.anims.create({
        key: 'walk',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', { frames: [0, 1, 2, 3] }),
        frameRate: 8,
        repeat: -1
    });

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'idle',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', { frames: [5, 6, 7, 8] }),
        frameRate: 8,
        repeat: -1
    });

    this.anims.create({
        key: 'kick',
        frames: this.anims.generateFrameNumbers('brawler', { frames: [10, 11, 12, 13, 10] }),
        frameRate: 8,
        repeat: 0,
        repeatDelay: 2000
    });

    this.player = this.physics.add.sprite(config.width / 2, config.height / 2, 370)
        .setScale(2)
        .play('idle');
}

function update() {
    let velocity = 50;
    if (this.cursors.left.isDown) {
        // Version One
        if (this.player.body.velocity.x == 0) {
            this.player.play('kick');
        } else if (!this.player.anims.isPlaying || this.player.anims.currentAnim.key != 'kick') {
            this.player.play('walk', true);
        }
        this.player.body.setVelocityX(-velocity);
        this.player.flipX = false;
    } else if (this.cursors.right.isDown) {
        // Version two
        if (this.player.body.velocity.x == 0) {
            this.player.play('kick');
            this.player.anims.chain('walk', true);
        }
        this.player.body.setVelocityX(velocity);
        this.player.flipX = true;
    } else {
        if(this.player.anims.currentAnim.key == 'walk'){
            this.player.play('idle');
        }
        this.player.body.setVelocityX(0);
    }
}

new Phaser.Game(config);
console.clear();
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser/dist/phaser.min.js"></script>
```